# Only root and pi user have audio

Tags: audio

I have raspi 3 with a Cirrus Logic audio card, with this kernel:
https://github.com/HiassofT/rpi-linux
complied from source

It is working, and I have audio for the root and pi user, however an arbitary newly added user does not have correct audio capabilities.

The new user in the audio group, it is in  the same groups as the default pi user.

The new user can see the sound card via aplay -l, even can play waw files via aplay, but nor VLC neither mplayer are working. They play audio files without showing any error, but there is no sound.

Comment: Just to clarify: `aplay` *does* make a sound but `mplayer` *does not*?

Comment: @goldilocks Yes aplay can play .waw files, while mplayer and vlc fail, regardless of the format.
For root and pi everything is ok

Comment: Try `grep pulse /etc/group`.  If there's a `pulseaudio` group (that will be distinct from the `audio` group), add the user to that, login again and try.   Many A/V  apps use have various audio backends and will use a default, but  `aplay` is an alsa specific tool.  If Mplayer is using a pulseaudio backend and either 1) there's a group for that you need to belong to or 2) pulseaudio isn't running, that may be a cause.  I'd think #1 would lead to an error but I've run into #2 before...

Comment: ...Have a look at "AUDIO OUTPUT OPTIONS" in `man mplayer` and try using it from the command line with `-ao alsa`.

Comment: mplayer -ao alsa works, thanks. Why pi user does not use puse and the new user does? Can I disable it as an alternative?

Comment: I've installed pulseaudio and now even mplayer -ao alsa file fails

Comment: What about `-ao pulse` then? ;)  IMO pulseaudio is more of a hassle unless you need it for some particular reason.  Everything *should* have a way to work directly through alsa, it's just a matter of finding out what it is.  I'd guess there's a config file somewhere you can set the default output, or worst case scenario you create an alias for the command.

Comment: E.g., `alias mplayer='mplayer -ao alsa'`, but you need that in a file that runs on login or before you use the GUI, unless you are always just invoking from the command line.

Comment: @goldilocks Not work either, but I found the reason:
The only important difference between the two users, that I never logged into the gui with pi before. So I logged in a mate session, and it lost the ability to play audio to via other apps, but aplay.
 So I removed pulseaudio from the system, then added a new user logged in to a Mate session, and filnaly it can play audio. My guess is pulse audio generated wrong config files for user on X logins.
The strange thing: I removed all dotted dirs/files from the previous user dir, but it still fails to play audio...

Comment: @goldilocks you are right I will use alsa only, if you write an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Simply deleting stuff whose purpose isn't clear to you is rarely a wise move, lol.  You might as well recreate the user from scratch now. That may not fix the problem, but otherwise you are up a creek having thrown your paddle into the water (and whittling one yourself is probably not the most direct course of action).

Comment: Lemme know for sure when you have it working with alsa and I'll summarize this (unless you want to do it yourself -- you can accept your own answer in 24 hours, although you'll only get points for other people's upvotes).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39737/discussion-between-atevm-and-goldilocks).

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this. Then I logged out and logged back in. My user was able to play mp3 now.

```
usermod -a -G audio USERNAME
```

Comment: I no longer have the device so cannot test this out, however the user was in the audio group and I relogged. Did you used a Cirrus Audio card?

Comment: not sure about the audio card. It's whatever came with Pi 4

Comment: It was a special case with this audio card https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/cirrus_logic_audio_card

The integrated on worked well